# image after binarization is coming as rotated

Tags: java, binary, grayscale

Here is my code for converting a png image to binary image form.Although sometime it convert one image to binary image form but on some other time it convert it to binary image form with image rotated to some angle..here buffered image is the input png image that i wana convert to binary form

```
public static byte[][] binarizeImage(BufferedImage bfImage){
        final int THRESHOLD = 160;
        int height = bfImage.getHeight();
        int width = bfImage.getWidth();
        byte[][] image = new byte[width][height];

        for(int i=0; i<width; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<height; j++){
                Color c = new Color(bfImage.getRGB(i,j));
                int red = c.getRed();
                int green = c.getGreen();
                int blue = c.getBlue();
                if(red<THRESHOLD && green<THRESHOLD && blue<THRESHOLD){
                    image[i][j] = 1;
                }else{
                    image[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

can anyone pls tel the problem.for some images it works for other it doesnt.i making use of getrgb function

EDIT: Just improving legibility.

Comment: By the looks of it you forgot to take into consideration that the image has 3 bytes for every pixel at the least: R, G, B.  So shouldn't the size of the width be * 3?  Then you would put for the 3 different pixels 1 or 0.  That might account for the rotation if you don't have enough data for each pixel.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond thats not a problem..i already tried using it..sadly i m just not able to find out the reason as why its happening